# Is function $y=\tan x$ uniformly continuous in the open interval $(0,\pi/2)\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Determine whether the function $y=\tan x$ is uniformly continuous in the open interval $(0,\pi/2)$.

I tried approaching it this way

Let $x,y  \in (0, \pi/2)$. Then

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\tan x-\tan y|={\left|{{\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y}\over \cos x\cos y}\right|}\le|\sin(x-y)|\le|x-y|$$

Selecting $\delta=\epsilon$ we have that the given function is uniformly continuous.

Where am i gong wrong ?

Comment: What is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow(\pi/2)^-} \tan x$? Then, for $x$ close to and less than $\pi/2$, how large can $|\tan x-\tan y|$ be for $y$ close to and less than $\pi/2$?

Comment: Hint: Every uniformly continuous function is $____$ on $____$ intervals.

Comment: @Did : but the interval here is not closed

Comment: This is irrelevant, one only uses that the real line is Archimedean.

Comment: @Did : I am little confused about using the theorem that every Uniformly continuous function is bounded in the bounded interval. Like for this question, $\tan x$ goes to $\infty$ only for $x=\pi /2$ but that is outside the interval. so how does that matter here ? I mean $\tan x$ would not be bounded in $[0,\pi /2]$ so how do we use it for $(0,\pi /2)$

Comment: "how does that matter here?" As already said, it does not matter. Every UC function is bounded on every bounded interval included in its domain of definition (and if the interval is not included in the domain of definition, the statement is meaningless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every uniformly continuous function is bounded on every bounded interval included in its domain of definition. The proof only uses that the real line is Archimedean.

Answer (score 5):

It is not uniform continuous. Consider $a_n=\pi/2 - 2^{-n}$, $b_n=\pi/2 - 4^{-n}$. Then

$$\left|\frac{\sin a_n}{\cos a_n} - \frac{\sin b_n}{\cos b_n}\right|=\left| \frac{\sin(a_n-b_n)}{\cos a_n\cos b_n}\right|=\frac{\sin(2^{-n}-4^{-n})}{\sin(2^{-n}) \sin (4^{-n})}\sim\frac{2^{-n}-4^{-n}}{2^{-n} \cdot 4^{-n}}\to\infty$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** For each $\delta >0$ you can cover $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ by finitely many intervals of length $\delta$. See did's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You erred in removing Cos x and Cos y from the denominator, when x tends to pi/2, cos x will tend to infinity and hence the LHS of your inequality will be a very large number, obviously greater then Sin(x-y)